# Representing/processing unstructured/general xml

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I'm about to manipulate XMLs (without schema) in Go and my goal is to achieve a simple framework without a hardwired internal representation of xml's structure.

I have a code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var decoder *xml.Decoder
var encoder *xml.Encoder

type Tokens struct {
    root     xml.Token
    children []Tokens
}

type Tokenizer interface {
    toStr() string
}

func setTokens(t xml.Token) Tokens {
    res := Tokens{}
    res.root = t

    res.children = make([]Tokens, 0)

    for {
        tok, err := decoder.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        t := setTokens(xml.CopyToken(tok))
        res.children = append(res.children, t)
    }

    return res
}

func (t Tokens) toStr() {
    encoder.EncodeToken(t.root)

    for i := range t.children {
        t.children[i].toStr()
    }
}

func main() {
    fc, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testXML.xml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    out, err := os.Create("./testOut.xml")

    decoder = xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(fc))
    encoder = xml.NewEncoder(out)

    t, err := decoder.Token()
    if err == io.EOF {
        return
    }

    tokens := setTokens(t)

    tokens.toStr()

    encoder.Encode(t)
}
```

An input xml like this:

```
<ParamSection SectVersion="1">
    <Version>22</Version>
</ParamSection>
```

And an output like this:

```
<ParamSection SectVersion="1">
&#x9;<Version>22</Version>
</ParamSection><StartElement><Name></Name><Attr><Name></Name><Value>1</Value></Attr></StartElement>
```

Which is more than nothing. There are two obvious problems:

- &#x9; istead of a \t (tabulator)
- <StartElement><Name></Name><Attr><Name></Name><Value>1</Value></Attr></StartElement>
  instead of nothing (Encoder seems to append the attribs of the first
  field).

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Not an answer but just some food for thoughts. I'd say the chief problem with your approach is the assumption that whatever tokenizer reads is always "root node (well, an XML document, strictly speaking, has only a single root node but OK) plus its children": this is not true for several reasons, and you have to "filter" tokens to only consider `xml.StartElement`-s as marking what you call "roots"; see [this](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Token) for which kinds of tokens the decoder might emit.

Comment: Now if we write a dumb decode + encode program, it generates an output identical to the input—[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_xAVXAxT6JJ), so I'd took it, add debugging printouts to make the decoding loop print all the tokens it gets from the decoder and then try to make sense of how to properly handle that.

Comment: Thanks for comments,
the first comment is true so I'll add some type assumptions, and the second comment is true, too, but obviously I start to modify data if I can read an xml, represent it in memory and can write back in a stable way. Maybe I checked it at wrong places but saw examples only for hardcoded xmls.

Comment: Another stuff strange for me is that on playground code You apply a simple loop + array instead of a recursion + a tree for describing xml (and still seems to work :-)

Comment: «apply a simple loop + array»: that's easy: no matter whether the data structure you're traversing appears to be a tree or not (or something even more involved), _the sequence_ of steps it takes to traverse the whole one naturally forms a simple list. What I wanted to stress is that while an XML document can (with certain philosophical assumptions) indeed be thought like a tree-like structure, you must be careful with detecting where an enclosing element starts and ends. And likewise "recreate" the same ordering of tokens when serializing.

Comment: Note that the &#x9; problem seems to exist in Your playground code, too, You, if I understand it well, added four spaces instead of the tab in the dummy data string for tabulation. Replace it with a tab and &#x9; pop up in the output.

Comment: That was not me but rather copy&paste function of my web browser, it seems. As to the problem, an interesting and often overlooked thing about XML is that whitespace is insignificant inside element tags (that is, `<foo bar="baz">` is the same as `<foo     bar = "baz"   >`, interpretation of whitespace _between_ the nodes is up to the processor (that is, it may or may not be considered significant based no who looks). And the generator is free to encode significant characters _which are not part of the markup_ using so-called "entities" (that `&#x9;` is one of them).

Comment: … This does not render a document invalid, but I understand but you'd rather have tabs rendered in a "more conventional" way. If you add `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", tok)` before the statement which appens a copy of the current token to the list of tokens, you'll see that your inter-node whitespace is dutifully considered by the parser as "character data": <https://play.golang.org/p/yiPCSx94cjI>. Note that if we ask the encoder to indent with a tab on each nesting level (via the call such as `enc.Indent("", "\t")`, the resulting XML will come out almost as you'd expect but both recorded instances…

Comment: …of the character data (with the original `\t` encoded as `&#x9;`) _will be rendered too._ That is precisely because the parser cannot read your mind and it hence cannot know whether these bits of character data are insignificant whitespace or not. To better understand why is that, consider this bit of XML: `<verse>The lyf so <em>short</em>,
The craft so hard to <strong>lerne!</strong>
<author>Chaucer</author> </verse>` — obviously the space after "so" and after "to" must be kept intact while the whitespace between `</author>` and `</verse>` is insignificant.

Comment: All-in-all, before (or at least in parallel with) attacking your problem you should gain more solid understanding of what XML actually is. I admit that [the specs](https://www.w3.org/XML/Core/#Publications) are mostly impenetrable for humans—at least if the reader has no prior knowledge and looks for some definitive reference material. So it's better to find and read a couple of introductory materials first.

Comment: Thanks for Your in-depth answer, I really appreciate that. I stepped Your (and many versions of my) code and I saw that these tabulations are represented in CharData fields (inside; properly as '10' and '9' bytes (\n and \t, respectively)) and for a reason the \n is handled the right way and \t is written out in a HTML-encoding or what. I checked the enc.Indent, but that I think that's a different stuff (reformatting the xml instead of hanling chardata correctly). My concern is that my unittesters check string-string equality and thus as a first step I need 100% precise handling of xml.

Comment: And again, thanks for dealing this so much.

Comment: PS what I don't understand is that why is that \t encoded in HTML and not handled the proper way.

Comment: Aha, the problem is unfortunately in xml.go:1918, where there is a case '\t': esc = escTab where escTab  = []byte("&#x9;") replacement without thinking. Needless to say, that function (escapeText) has an escapeNewline option for setting newlines properly, but lacks an escapeTab where I should set proper tab handling.

Comment: Only thing is left behind is to find the most elegant way to replace &#x9; to \t in StringBuilder.

Comment: …and sometimes called "entities", which is not strictly correct but entrenched; [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref) is what the spec says on them). So the problem you're facing is cosmetic: there's no difference in handling a byte with code 0x09 (an ASCII TAB character) or a sequence `&#x9;`—as far as a conforming XML processor is concerned: they _must_ be processed in exactly the same way. But, look, consider again what I said about the character data between tags: it's _you_ who decides what it means. You might just drop all whitespace-only chardata blocks which happen…

Comment: …to occur between tags, and then rely on the indentation set on an encoder instance to produce "canonical" indentation, or you may preserve chardata blocks and then provide a way for them to be encoded using your custom code (see [this](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) for a start). But before everything else, _pease read up on what XML is_ first as you still appear to be bashing at the problem before gaining solid understanding of the problem domain, and this is a sure path to failure.

Comment: And yeah, not a surprise, Go doesn't handle [CDATA[]] fields, too (throws them away). I feel I would be closer if I wrote the whole .xml processing stuff from a scratch.

Comment: PS my case of .xmls are quite special, as every text field is encapsulated in CDATA fields and thus there are practically no HTML encoded characters like &#x9;.

Comment: Go processes CDATA sections just fine. May be you means that the cycle decode→tokens→encode does not produce them in a way exactly as they have been read, but then again—somehow preserving the properly of generating the output _exactly_ matching the input is a much larger task than what one can sensibly require from a general purpose library.

Comment: As I remember, in Python (where standard library xml processing was not without problems, too) lxml used the 'tail' variable, and wrote stuff after node closing element "</blabla>" there and stuff there wasn't encoded into HTML (as it was used mostly for tabulating and stuff). That was kind of a best practice.